# Sending jquery request to a PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a function which checks if a search in the pickup address contains an airport as follows:-

```
function checkIsAirport(str) {

var myRegExp = /\bAIRPORT\b/i;

return str.match(myRegExp);

}


// Check if label contains an airport..
    if (checkIsAirport(label.html()) != null &&
        label.parent().parent().attr('title') == "Pickup") {

//FUNCTION

}
```

Basically what I am needing to do is add a 'surcharge' of 'x' amount if the pickup contains an airport address. So if a airport is set to Gatwick, this is then sent to tariff.fare.controller.php which will add 'x' to the fare. I was just wondering how would be the best way about doing this.

Also, if a user changes the pickup from an airport to a none airport address, 'x' would have to be subtracted from the fare.

Any help would be much appreciated!

:: EDIT ::

Just to add, to achieve this I am wanting to use AJAX. As soon as a user enters an airport in the pickup address a request needs to be sent to my TariffFareController class to the following function:

```
private static function getFinalFare($fare) {

    $final_fare = ($fare * self::$fare_factor);

    if (self::$str_wait_return == "true") {
        $final_fare = $final_fare * 2;
    }

    if (self::$str_return == "true" && self::$return_date != "false" && self::$return_time != "false") {

        // We need to calc to fare based on the return date and time
        $return_fare = self::getFare(1);

        // Append to final fare
        $final_fare = $final_fare + $return_fare;

    }

    // Create new journey object with the info that we have so far

    /*$journey = new Journey($journey_id,$pickup,$dropoff,$vias,$distance,$vehicle,
                    $date_time,$return_journey,$meet_greet,$extras);*/

    return number_format($final_fare,2);

}
```

so that I can read the 'surcharge' value from the database and then add this to the fare calculation.

Comment: Are you looking for Ajax or am I completely misunderstanding your question. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: best way of doing what... the math, user display, store and or send data to server or ...??? Really not clear what you need. Please outline details and what you have tried and supply some html to go along with it

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't put the check for AIRPORT in your JS. If the user decides to open up Firebug and edit the JS, they could easily bypass the extra tariff. Also, the tariff might not be added at all if the user has JS disabled in their browser. The best solution would be to handle all of this logic on the server's side with PHP.

Nevertheless, here's an example of an AJAX POST request to a PHP script:

```
$.post("checkTarriff.php", { id: identifyingId },
 function(data){
   console.log(data);
 }, "json");
```

Comment: Pretty much this and then some. I've been that guy in the past that edit's JS to get around taxes.

Comment: Thank you for this, if it can be bypassed then how would I go about doing this server side if I am needing to check if a value in a textbox contains an airport address?

Comment: @nsilva Preferably when they submit the form that the textbox is in.

Comment: Ah okay, the only problem is the fare calculation calculates as soon as you input a 'pickup' and 'destination' using a default car, and it goes up or down depending on the time selected, date, car type etc...

Comment: Could you not slot the AIRPORT check into those fare calculations? That would probably be the best solution.

Comment: how would I check that $("txt-pickup").val() contains an airport using PHP? that's why I thought I would have to check in JQ, and send the request to PHP to add to fare